# How do i move files with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have tried creating a batch file that moves mods from the gta v directory to another when i need to play online. I wrote this so far:

```
move E:/Epic Games/GTAV/TrainerV.asi C:/Users/example/Desktop
```

I got this error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Can someone tell me how to do it right? I would appreciate it.

Comment: What happens when you run that same command manually from a command prompt? Also note that the path separator on Windows is the backslash (`\`), not the forward slash you're using. What does typing `move /?` at the command prompt tell you about the syntax?

Comment: I ran the command from the command prompt,same error, ill try the backslash,see if that works.the move /? tells me the same thing that i read on most sites, sorry im not that familiar with batch or any other coding language.

Comment: Use `""`, if there are spaces in paths you must group the path with quotes `""`

Comment: @NekoMusume do you mean move "C:\...\..."

Comment: @cheeselover69 Yes.

Comment: @NekoMusume That worked thank you

Comment: Also thank you for @KenWhite for the backslash tip

Comment: @cheeselover69: I've rolled back your edit. Adding *SOLVED* or *Already Answered* to your question is inappropriate. You can either write an answer in the space below if you want to share an answer with other readers, wait for someone else to do so, or delete your question using the link below the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to operate with any file with a space in cmd/batch, you need to group them with quotes `""` and since

```
E:\Epic Games\GTAV\TrainerV.asi
       ^ Here
```

has spaces, you need to surround it with quotes. A good practice is to have quotes anyways. The correct syntax is:

```
move "E:\Epic Games\GTAV\TrainerV.asi" "C:\Users\example\Desktop"
```

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple issues with your current command.

First, paths containing spaces must be surrounded in double quotes.

Second, Windows uses the backslash `\` instead of the forward slash `/` as the path separator. While the forward slash might be accepted in some cases, it won't work in all, so it's better to use the proper `\`.

The corrected version of your code would be

```
move "E:\Epic Games\GTAV\TrainerV.asi" C:\Users\example\Desktop
```